# How can I open the command line, execute a program within, give it some values and write the return values into a file (with php)

Tags: php, cmd

Thats what I've been trying to do for days now, and I can't find a solution.

I have managed to launch the cmd-line OR any given program via php, but I need a program to start within the cmd-line, give it a static command and write the return values into a .txt.

What I want to do

1.The user clicks on a link 
2.That executes a php script which automatically:
 -opens the command line
 -starts a program within the command line
 -enters somme commands (e.g process the file, write result to a .txt-file)

It just doesnt work, no matter how I've tried it.

I just don't understand how I should approach the whole thing.

Edit:

Everything is supposed to run on the server! I want to start a biometrics program that compares a picture with another one and return a percentage value.

And I am running windows with xampp.

Comment: That sounds like a really terrible idea, for a whole host of reasons.  It would have to execute it on the server, not on the users computer obviously.  Then you would need to use this probably http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Everything is supposed to run on the server!

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I execute cmd commands through a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727941/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-through-batch-file?rq=1)

This helped me out a lot. I now have a batch file that does the following:

```
@echo
c:\
cd C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\OpenBR-0.5.0-win64\bin 
start br -algorithm FaceRecognition -compare C:\Users\XXX\Pictures\1.jpg C:\Users\XXX\Pictures\2.jpg C:\Users\fxw2_000\Desktop\result.csv
pause
```

Aaaaaaand it works. Awesome!