# Run Teradata SQL Assistant via a batch script

Tags: batch-file, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to Run a teradata SQL script via a batch script and export the details.
I have managed to execute the whole thing in DOS which is great
Im just not sure how to package it up
Below is my very average attempt. COuld anyone point me in the right direction?

The SQL is `SELECT DATE`

```
@title Optional Title
@echo off

C:\'Program Files (x86)'\Teradata\Client\15.00\Teradata SQL Assistant\
Sqla -c DB_NAME -f "C:\Temp\test.sql" -e "c:\Temp\test_output.log"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on another different question on Stack Overflow

[How do I execute cmd commands through a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727941/how-do-i-execute-cmd-commands-through-a-batch-file)

This basically does what i need or at least points me in the correct direction

Thank you for your time

Comment: Glad you found an answer. SQL Assistant is not necessarily the best tool for batch execution. For non-trivial batch work you might want to investigate BTEQ and/or Teradata Parallel Transporter (TPT).